# Is it safe using $Config{perlpath} in system/exec/open?

Tags: perl

Assume that I have following code to open filehandle:

```
open my $fh, "command1 | command2 |";
```

I found `command1` may output that `command2` can not handle well, so I'm trying to insert a perl filter between `command1` and `command2` to deal with them:

```
use Config;
open my $fh, "command1 | $Config{perlpath} -ple 'blah blah' | command2 |";
```

My questions are:

1. Is it OK to use `$Config{perlpath}` in system call directly?
2. Calling own perl binary seems nuts.  Are there any better solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Shorter version of `$Config{perlpath}`: [`$^X`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#EXECUTABLE_NAME)

Comment: Definitely a sin. But a minor one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it OK to use $Config{perlpath} in system call directly?

Relatively. It's about as portable as the rest of your code (which already depends on running on something unix-ish). There's some security worry, but I'd say not a very large one because someone who can affect the value of that variable already has scope to cause havoc. `$^X` is probably safer in that regard. You might want to try quoting it using [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) just for safety, since you can't bypass the shell in the midst of a pipeline.

> Calling own perl binary seems nuts. Are there any better solutions?

Depends on your definition of "better". There's definitely another way around, which is to run both `command1` and `command2` separately, process `command1`'s output in your original perl process, hand it to `command2`, and read `command2`'s output. However, you have to be careful how you do it. There are two safe ways.

The first way is easier, but takes more time and memory: run `command1` first, read and process all of its output into a string, then run `command2` providing the buffered output as input. The best way to do this is to use [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) to handle `command2`'s input and output (and maybe both commands, just for consistency); if you try to just print all the data to `command2`'s input handle and then read all the output you can deadlock, but IPC::Run will interleave reads and writes if necessary behind the scenes, and give you a nice easy interface.

The second way is more complicated but closer in behavior to the original: you need some kind of async framework like [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async) or [POE](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE), using its classes for process construction, and set up handlers to communicate between them, do your filtering, and gather the output.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/arodland/bf5de98dfb4503583fb1e51ae3aa0c67) a tested toy example of that (gist because it's a couple screenfuls of code) that does the equivalent of `ls | perl -pe '$_ = uc' | rev`, except with the middle part of the pipeline running in the parent perl process. You may never use it, but I thought it was worth illustrating.